# disable tooltips in TinyMCE version 4

Tags: tinymce

i use the last version of TinyMCE in my project, i install it successfully and every things work. when mouse over on Textarea a tooltip be appear, **how can i disable tooltips?** i found this but dos not work.

```
<style>
    .mce-tooltip {
    display: none !important;
    }

</style>
```

- the tooltip text is about text aria and TinyMCE Hot key like alt+0
  that i don't need this tooltips

how can i use initial method or any solution for solve it.

Answer (score 0):

by use this java script code my problem be solved,

```
 document.getElementById('message_ifr').removeAttribute('title');
```